# Taking a moving average in a nested data frame

Tags: r, time-series, apply, purrr, moving-average

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
region = rep(1:3, each = 45),
term  = rep(rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 15), 3), 
period = rep(rep(1:15, each = 3), 3),
X = rnorm(nrow(df)) 
)
```

I have a nested dataframe, in which I have measures for 3 variables ("a", "b", and "c" `term` column, with the corresponding measure given in the `X` column), recorded over 15 time periods and across 3 regions. I want to create a new column, `X_moving_av`, which is the average of "a", "b", and "c" respectively over the previous 3 periods within that region. So, for example, take region 1, term "b", in period 10. In a new column, `X_moving_av`, I want the following number to appear:

```
with(df, ave(X[region==1 & term=="b" & period==10], X[region==1 & term=="b" & period==9], X[region==1 & term=="b" & period==8]))
```

Then the cell beneath would be:

```
with(df, ave(X[region==1 & term=="c" & period==10], X[region==1 & term=="c" & period==9], X[region==1 & term=="c" & period==8]))
```

...and so on for the whole df, (excluding the first 2 periods, for which I don't have 3 periods of measures).

What's the best way to iterate this? I actually have a lot of variables recorded in the `term` column (i.e. many more than just "a", "b", and "c"), and hundreds of regions and periods, so I need something as general as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a time series case?

If it is

https://github.com/tidyverts/tsibble

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
    region = rep(1:3, each = 45, length.out = 135),
    term  =  rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 3, lenght.out = 135), 
    period = rep(1:15, each = 3 , lenght.out = 135),
    x =    rnorm(135)
)

library(tsibble)

Your_Answer <- df %>% 
  group_by(region,term,period) %>% 
  mutate(X_MA = slide_dbl(x, ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE), .size = 3))
```

Comment: This definitely looks on the right track, but this isn't what the dataset looks like. I have 3 regions,  and 15 periods, then for each period I have three variables that are measured. I simply want the average of each variable, within the region, over the previous 3 periods (i.e. the mean of the current period and the previous two periods).

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(
  region = rep(1:3, each = 45),
  term  = rep(rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 15), 3), 
  period = rep(rep(1:15, each = 3), 3),
  X = rnorm(nrow(df)) 
)

Your_Answer <- df %>% 
  group_by(region,term) %>% 
  mutate(X_MA = slide_dbl(X, ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE), .size = 3))
```